# Separating a line into two different objects

Tags: java, object

I'm not sure how to implement this.

Suppose i have two classes Dog and Cat

```
public class Dog
{
    private int a, b;
    private double c;
    //Constructors etc
}

public class Cat
{
    private int x, y;
    private char z;
    //Constructors etc
}
```

I'm also given a a string

"a, b, c/x,y,z"

The string can be of any combination i.e Cat/Dog, Dog/Cat ,Dog/Dog etc the third value of each part is either going to be a double or a char

I have split the String and made two arrays.
This is what i have so far:

```
public void object ()
{

    //My code to Split the line on "/" into 2 parts
    //splits the part on "," to create two String arrays

    //oneArray[] is [a,b,c] twoArray[] is [x,y,z]

    oneArray[2] = ?? //Not sure how to create the right object that matches the data type
    twoArray[2] = ??
 }
```

How do i create two Objects no matter the string combination when the third value is of a different data type?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
List<Object> animalsList = new ArrayList<>(); // Will contains list of all animals
String input = "Cat/Dog, Dog/Cat ,Dog/Dog "; // Sample Input List
String [] inputEntries = input.split(","); // Separating based on comma
for(String inputEntry: inputEntries)
{
   String [] animals = inputEntry.split("/");
   for(String animal: animals)
   {
    objectList.add(animal.equalsIgnoreCase("Cat")?new Cat():new Dog());  
                                                         /\                                                             
                                                         ||
                                                         ||
                                  You can pass the values to constructor from here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code solves your problem in a more object oriented way:

utility method(Checks whether third elements is parse-able to Double or defaults to String):

```
private List<Animal> splitLine(String line)
{
    List<Animal> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] elements = line.split("/");

    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            Cat cat = new Cat(Integer.valueOf(elements[i].charAt(0)), Integer.valueOf(elements[i].charAt(1)), Double.valueOf(elements[i].charAt(
                    2)));
            objectList.add(cat);

        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            Dog dog = new Dog(Integer.valueOf(elements[i].charAt(0)), Integer.valueOf(elements[i].charAt(1)), "" + elements[i].charAt(2));
            objectList.add(dog);

        }

    }
    return objectList;
}
```

Common Interface:

```
interface Animal
{

}
```

Class Dog:

```
class Dog implements Animal
{
    private Integer a;
    private Integer b;
    private String c;

    public Dog(Integer a, Integer b, String c)
    {
        super();
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

Class Cat:

```
class Cat implements Animal
{
    private Integer x;
    private Integer y;
    private Double c;

    public Cat(Integer x, Integer y, Double c)
    {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```